# Word 2013 - footnote custom balance?

Tags: ms-word

I searched a lot and couldn't find anything about customizing the balance in footnote of the Microsoft word. It is actually quite useful since it's really common for affiliations in scientific papers. This is the footnote affiliation section in the word file of the IEEE conference template:

[image]

However, this template, which is in old **.doc** format, is not compatible with the insert->Equation of the MS-word and the document should be converted to a newer version (**.docx**). After conversion the footnote goes like this

[image]

What I found in microsoft [web page](http://%20support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2740483) is that:

> *By default, Word 2013 positions footnotes in columns when a document has multiple columns. Additionally, footnotes begin in the first
>   column on the page regardless of where the footnote reference appears
>   in the body text. Word 2013 balances the footnotes across the footnote
>   columns.*

So, is it possible to customize the balance in the footnote ?!

Comment: I couldn't add these two links so I will add them here: 
That microsoft webpage: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2740483
A common template with this issue: 
http://embc.embs.org/2016/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2015/12/4-Page-Template.doc

Comment: I added the pictures and KB link to your text. But actually, I think your question belongs on an end-user and not a programmer's site. If Word can't do it in the UI, there's nothing VBA can do to help. Either "Super User" here on Stack Exchange or the Word IT Pro forum on Technet might be good places to ask...

Comment: I found a script which lead to a workaround for the problem. If you find the question and the answer redundant please remove it. Otherwise I will be happy if it helps someone one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that after converting the .doc file to newer formats the footnote which is somehow hidden cannot be deleted. So the workaround is to use the script which I found [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=663041) and can be run in VBS editor of the MS-Word (alt+F11):

```
Sub DeleteFootnotes()

Dim c As Object
For Each c In ThisDocument.Footnotes
    c.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

So the hidden footnote will be deleted and then I put a text-box with no-filled outline which resembles the exact same thing.

[image]

Comment: Useful approach, glad you found it. Something that's not clear in your original question is that you're converting files from the old *.doc file format. I think this is important information, so if you have a moment to use the "Edit" link below the question to add that it would be good :-)

Comment: Thank you! just fixed it  :)